# udev rule executing bot not mounting (raspbian stretch)

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, udev, raspbian

I've been able to automount on previous Raspbian versions, but the rule is not executing the "mount" on stretch.

The Rule:

```
KERNEL!="sd[a-z][0-9]", GOTO="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"  
# Import FS infos  
IMPORT{program}="/sbin/blkid -o udev -p %N"  
# Get a label if present, otherwise specify one  
ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}!="", ENV{dir_name}="%E{ID_FS_LABEL}"  
ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}=="", ENV{dir_name}="usbhd-%k"  


# Global mount options  
ACTION=="add", ENV{mount_options}="relatime"  
# Filesystem-specific mount options  

ACTION=="add",ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}=="vfat|ntfs",ENV{mount_options}="$env{mount_options},utf8,gid=100,umask=002"  
# Mount the device  

ACTION=="add", RUN+="/home/pi/11-media-by-label.sh /bin/mount -o $env{mount_options} /dev/%k /media/%E{dir_name}"  

ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/mkdir -p /media/%E{dir_name}", RUN+="/bin/mount -o $env{mount_options} /dev/%k /media/%E{dir_name}"  
# Clean up after removal  
ACTION=="remove", ENV{dir_name}!="", RUN+="/bin/umount -l /media/%E{dir_name}", RUN+="/bin/rmdir /media/%E{dir_name}"  
# Exit  
LABEL="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"
```

Notice it runs `ACTION=="add", RUN+="/home/pi/11-media-by-label.sh /bin/mount -o $env{mount_options} /dev/%k /media/%E{dir_name}"`

Which contains:

```
`pi@tv:~ $ cat /home/pi/11-media-by-label.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "11-media-by-label-auto-mount.rules: $@" >> /tmp/11-media-by-label-auto-mount.rules.log
```

`
This runs and produces:

`pi@tv:~ $ cat /tmp/11-media-by-label-auto-mount.rules.log 
11-media-by-label-auto-mount.rules: /bin/mount -o relatime,utf8,gid=100,umask=002 /dev/sda1 /media/USB_DISK`

The "mount" ACTION on the previous line looks to have the correct format because when I manually paste it into a terminal window as:
`pi@tv:~ $ sudo /bin/mount -o relatime,utf8,gid=100,umask=002 /dev/sda1 /media/USB_DISK`
it works perfectly.

Afer a `sudo udevadm control --log-priority=info`, syslog contains:

`/var/log/syslog:Jun 10 17:34:54 tv systemd-udevd[121]: Process '/bin/mount -o relatime,utf8,gid=100,umask=002 /dev/sda1 /media/USB_DISK' failed with exit code 32.`

Which just resolves to "Mount failure".

(I also get a exit code of 1 with the mkdir -p, which looks like a permissions problem, but the log files are created by root, so I know it's really root.

Any ideas?